# Get URL of image placed in my Footer area in Wordpress as widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I created widget area (Footer area) for my Wordpress theme where I can add Image widget. The thing is that I would like to get url of image that is into my Footer area as widget. Is there a function for that?

In functions.php I add:

```
function widgets() {
    register_sidebar(
    array(
    'name' => 'Footer area',
    'id'=> 'footer_area1'
    )
    );
}
```

In my header.php I add:

```
<div id="Footer">
<?php 
dynamic_sidebar('footer_area1'); 

?>
</div>
```

Now, I can add all sorts of widgets (Image, Text, Meta, Menu etc.) into that area. But when I add Image widget that is default widget, I would like to get URL of image/picture that is placed in that area through Image widget. How can I get url?

I hope that clears the question.

[image: Get URL of picture inside Image widget]

Comment: incomprehensible question, can you formulate please ? And eventually published the source code of your widget ?

Comment: Sorry for incomprehensible question. I edit question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Sorry but it's always incomprehensible :), are you French ? By the way, The call of your "footer sidebar" have to be in the footer.php (not the header.php).

Comment: Not French but poor English :-)

Comment: Try to use google trad and explain with maximum detail :)

Comment: Check screenshot

Comment: You want to put an image into this widget ? There is already an image in this widget? You want to get the URL in PHP for re-use it ?

Comment: Get URL to re-use it.

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_area1' ); ?>
```

As per the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dynamic_sidebar/

**Edit**

If you would like to extend the Image Widget, you can try look at using this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget

But for a much more easier approach, I'd suggest uploading your image to Media Library and then copying the image url from there and pasting it into a custom widget area.

Answer (score -2):

Widget settings are stored in the options table. You can get the content of an option field with get_option(). Replace MY_WIDGET with the actual ID of your widget:

```
$widget = get_option( 'widget_MY_WIDGET' );
```

Use print_r to inspect the returned value (false if option does not exist) and get an idea of how to grab the desired value:

```
print_r( $widget );
```

**EDIT :**

To find the widget id :

1. Open Appearance->Widgets
2. On top of the screen, find “Screen Options” and open it
3. Click on “Enable Accessibility Mode”
4. Find a widget for which you want to know ID and click the “Edit” button
5. In the address bar, find “editwidget=something” where “something” is the ID you are looking for

Comment: Where to find out widget ID?

Comment: I found out my ID, but code your doesn't work for me.<?php echo 2; $widget = get_option('widget_media_image-3'); print_r( $widget ); ?>

Comment: Also, ID changes when I delete Image widget and add another one. So, that solution isn't good for me.

Comment: This is incorrect. The user has already provided the id i.e. `footer_area1`. Besides that, the sidebar id does not get saved as a option_name in the database, it's saved in an array fashion in the database.